# Is there a way to create user groups?

Tags: group, user

I was looking for some extension that could give this possibility, but I did't find anyone.

Has anyone had this need? How do you solved?

Those groups would be for example: attendants, it, managers, hr, and so on. This data will be used in others systems.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is in Magento as standard.

Magento1: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-groups.html

Magento2: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/customers/customer-groups.html

Answer (score 1):

If youre talking about admin user groups, then you need to start managing roles:

- Magento 1: http://merch.docs.magento.com/ce/user_guide/store-operations/permissions-user-new.html
- Magento 2: http://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/system/permissions-user-roles.html

Comment: thank you for your answer! But with user roles one user just can have one role, and what I need is an user be able to have many roles.

Comment: Well it sounds like youre confusing roles and resources. One role = several resources. You can create an admin role that can access the sales menu as well as the reports menu and another admin role that can only access the products menu for example.